# SD to USB Adapter: Will the SD card appear as a USB device?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, driver, c++

My colleague and I are writing an endurance test for SD cards (running read/write/erase block cycles). We're considering using an Raspberry Pi 3 to run the tests on.

The issue is we will be using full sized SD cards, so a SD to USB adapter will have to be used. We need to get to the driver level so we can issue commands to the SD card. However, we are concerned the adapter will cause the SD card to appear as a USB device and we will not be able to issue commands.

Will the SD card appear as a USB device? Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you insist on using a Raspberry when it's clearly not the right hardware? Get a laptop with a card reader.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is not an issue then you might consider using the SPI bus on the Raspberry Pi to interface with the SD card. You can do this with one of the many [interface modules](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_CAds=&_ex_kw=&_fpos=&_fspt=1&_mPrRngCbx=1&_nkw=Micro+SD+Card+Module+SPI&_sacat=&_sadis=&_sop=12&_udhi=&_udlo=&_fosrp=1) that are available (mostly for Arduino) or even [directly connect](https://hackaday.com/2009/08/18/cheap-sd-card-cradle/) to the card to be tested.

Once connected you can use write your own low-level driver, a quick search came up with some interesting hits that will set you on your way:

https://hackaday.com/2013/08/19/rescuing-an-sd-card-with-an-arduino/

https://github.com/search?q=SD+card+SPI&type=Repositories

https://www.microchip.com/forums/m530149.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using an USB SD card adapter won't work if you need driver level access. If you really want to use Raspberry Pi one of the older models can mount a large SD card. An alternate option might be to instead use a laptop with built in SD card reader.